# Can ints be passed where a Windows Handle is expected in Python ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I have the following code:

```
GetForegroundWindow = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow
GetWindowTextLength = windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW
GetWindowText = windll.user32.GetWindowTextW

hwnd = GetForegroundWindow() # Get handle to foreground window. Here hwnd is a Python int.
length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd) # Get length of the window text in title bar. Here hwnd is expected to be a Windows Handle.
buff = create_unicode_buffer(length + 1) # Create buffer to store the window title buff
    
GetWindowText(hwnd, buff, length + 1) # Get window title and store in buff

print(buff.value) # print the value of buff
```

On line 4, a handle is retrieved, which in ctypes is assumed to be a Python int. On the next line, it is passed where a Windows handle is expected. Is Python automatically converting it into the correct type? Don't we have to convert it explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don’t assume. Set `.argtypes` and `.restype` on each function to inform `ctypes` what the argument types and return type are. For example on 64-bit Python the handle is 64 bits and the assumed `c_int` return value will truncate it to 32 bits.

For example, extending your code using some predefined Windows types provided:

```
from ctypes import wintypes as w
...
GetForegroundWindow.argtypes = ()
GetForegroundWindow.restype = w.HWND
```

Now the correct value will be returned, regardless of OS. Repeat for other functions used and parameters will be type-checked and checked for number of arguments and return values will be correct.