# ctypes gdi32.GetPixel() returning inaccurate values - python

Tags: python, ctypes, getpixel

I am trying to grab the color of a pixel on screen.
GetPixel() is giving me something close to the actual color, but different every time.

I've tried setting the dpi awareness but that has not solved the issue.

This is my current code:

```
import time
import ctypes
DC = ctypes.windll.user32.GetDC(0)
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(2)

def getpixel(x, y):
    return tuple(int.to_bytes(ctypes.windll.gdi32.GetPixel(DC,x,y), 3, "little"))

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(getpixel(0, 0))
```

This is what it outputs:

```
(116, 106, 99)
(100, 91, 85)
(113, 104, 98)
(114, 105, 99)
(100, 92, 87)
(114, 105, 100)
(113, 103, 96)
(100, 92, 87)
(110, 100, 94)
```

Comment: Code works as is for me and follows the pixel color of the upper left of my screen, but *usually* problems are due to ignoring setting `.argtypes` and `restype` correctly for each function used.  For example, `HDC` is type defined as a `void *`, which is 64-bit on 64-bit system, but `.restype` defaults to `ctypes.c_int` which is 32-bit which would truncate the value if it is large enough.

Comment: There is also this note on [SetDpiProcessAwareness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-setprocessdpiawareness): "It is recommended that you set the process-default DPI awareness via application manifest. ... Setting the process-default DPI awareness via API call can lead to unexpected application behavior."  You may be seeing this "unexpected application behavior".

Comment: @MarkTolonen I do not fully understand your comment but I've tried adding the line 'ctypes.windll.gdi32.GetPixel.argtypes=[ctypes.c_int64,ctypes.c_int64,ctypes.c_int64]'. I'm not sure if this is what you meant though.

Comment: No, the argument types and return value should match the documented parameters.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65614099/235698) for an example.  There are predefined Windows types like HDC and HWND so you don't have to guess.  The last two parameters are `int`, which is `c_int` in `ctypes`.

Answer (score 0):

The OP code worked for me as is, but it does have the risk that the HDC returned could be truncated if it doesn't fit in 32 bits (the default return value if `.restype` is not defined for the function.

Here's a fully-specified example that should work properly on a 32- or 64-bit Windows OS. It's overkill, but guarantees all the types are converted correctly between C and Python.  It's extended to read the color at the cursor position:

```py
import time
import ctypes as ct
import ctypes.wintypes as w

HRESULT = w.LONG

class COLORREF(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('r', ct.c_ubyte),
                ('g', ct.c_ubyte),
                ('b', ct.c_ubyte),
                ('unused', ct.c_ubyte))
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'COLORREF(r={self.r}, g={self.g}, b={self.b})'

user32 = ct.WinDLL('user32')
GetDC = user32.GetDC
GetDC.argtypes = w.HWND,
GetDC.restype = w.HDC
GetCursorPos = user32.GetCursorPos
GetCursorPos.argtypes = w.PPOINT,
GetCursorPos.restype = w.BOOL

shcore = ct.WinDLL('shcore')
SetProcessDpiAwareness = shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness
SetProcessDpiAwareness.argtypes = ct.c_int,
SetProcessDpiAwareness.restype = HRESULT

gdi32 = ct.WinDLL('gdi32')
GetPixel = gdi32.GetPixel
GetPixel.argtypes = w.HDC, ct.c_int, ct.c_int
GetPixel.restype = COLORREF

hdc = GetDC(None)
SetProcessDpiAwareness(2)
p = w.POINT()
while True:
    time.sleep(.1)
    GetCursorPos(ct.byref(p))
    print(f'({p.x}, {p.y}) -> {GetPixel(hdc, p.x, p.y)}')
```